# How often could Bink's mother use her talent?

Tags: magic, piers-anthony, xanth

In *A Spell For Chameleon*, Bink's mother is introduced in the beginning of the book as having the talent of reversing time for 5 seconds with her unaffected by this time lapse. So she can fix a small mistake easily like a glass falling, etc.

How often could she use this gift, and why isn't she considered a Magician cause of it?

If she could use it as often as she wants, then couldn't she simply reverse time 5 seconds at a time over and over till she reached a time several years in the past?

And why can't she be classified as a Magician if she can bend time itself, even for only a few seconds at a time?

Comment: I never got that as well.  This can be world-changing when placed correctly.

Comment: This is awfully close to [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22705/how-is-a-person-identified-to-have-a-magician-caliber-talent).

Comment: The answer is that she can use it every 5 seconds. I will find the exact quote's location in the books, but, there is a part of one of the other books where Ivy drops a pinwheel cookie, and Bink's mother reverses time, but Ivy never remembers to not drop the cookie. I think they said this repeated 3 or 4 times. The reason she's not considered a magician is because of the above, her talent is mostly useless. No one could ever manage to remember not to do what they were about to do and so this is what usually happened. I'll find you an exact quote.

Answer (score 7):

She seemed able to use it as often as she liked, but not recursively. There is an instance in A Spell for Chameleon of Bink being caught in a poison cloud, and she replayed him multiple times until Roland managed to stun him. If she were able to travel further than 5 seconds with repeated uses, it's likely that she would have, and Roland's intervention would have been unnecessary.